# How to keep a <div> at the bottom of another <div> with scrolling elements behind it

Tags: html, css

I have a <div id = 'body-box> and and at the bottom I have an input for text .

I want  to stay at the bottom of the  while the chat messages scroll behind it. The  stays in line and gets pushed down as more chat elements are added in.

I would like the input form to stay at the bottom while still within . What am I doing wrong in my css currently because this is not being achieved. Thanks!

```
</head>
  <body style="background-image: url(./images/background.svg)">
    <div id = 'bodybox'>
      

      <div id = 'chat-message-list'>
        <div class = "message-row you-message">
          <div class = "message-content">
            
            <div class = "message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
            <div class = "message-time">Apr 16</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "message-row you-message">
          <div class = "message-content">
            <div class = "message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
            <div class = "message-time">Apr 16</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      <div id = 'chat-form'>
          <input id = 'input' type = 'text' placeholder="What would you like to know"/>
          <button id = 'sendbutton'>SEND</button>
      </div>
    


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
#chat-form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-flex;
  
}

body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  /*display: grid;*/
}

#bodybox {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F6FB;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Did you already manage to the auto scroll to keep chat messages at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `sticky` positioning to the form (instead of `absolute`, which you started with), remove the hard-coded `height` of the form, and achieve what you're after.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.

In your case the relatively-positioned parent `bodybox` is acting as the nearest block-level ancestor, allowing us to pin the form to the bottom of the element.

**Demo**

```css
#chat-form {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: calc(50% - 80px);
}

body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  /*display: grid;*/
}

#bodybox {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F6FB;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div id='bodybox'>


  <div id='chat-message-list'>
    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">

        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">

        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">

        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">

        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">

        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message-row you-message">
      <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="message-time">Apr 16</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='chat-form'>
      <input id='input' type='text' placeholder="What would you like to know" />
      <button id='sendbutton'>SEND</button>
    </div>



  </div>
```

**Link**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/vqfawb8s/10/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer I was able to get it to work!

Comment: @MattLaszcz Good to hear. If you're satisfied, please mark my answer as the selected one so I can receive credit.